# jQuery unknown error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to make a small and simple web app to calculate person’s age. If I compile my program it gives an error of “cant read length property of null”.I dont know why it is having arr as null. I tried to check my arr and run it in chrome developers tool and it is giving desired results. For example if we include 12/13/1995 in input, arr should be of length 4. But it is giving null error if I check console of developer tools… I couldnt figure out the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").focus(function() { //whenever user focus at input placeholder value should be mm/dd/yyyy
    $("input").attr("placeholder", "mm/dd/yyyy");
  });
  
  $("button").on("click", function() { //on click function on button GO
    var $inp = $("input").val(); //getting the value of input field
    var regex = /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/gi; //regular expression for date format
  
    if (regex.test($inp) === false) { //if format is not followed input is invalid
      $("input").attr("placeholder", "Please write valid input").val("");
    }
    
    var arr = regex.exec($inp); //making array of input field value ['12/13/1995','12','13','1995']
    var numarr = [];
    
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { //loop to convert string into numbers
      var n = Number(arr[i]); //converting into numbers
    
      if (i === 1 && n > 12 || i === 2 && n > 31) { //if invalid input day is 32 or month is 13
        $("input").attr("placeholder", "Please write valid input").val("");
      } else {
        numarr.push(n); //if valid push that number into numarr. 
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="head">
  <h1>Whats my alive time</h1>
</div>
<div class="container text-center" id="enter">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <h3 style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 0.5em; ">Enter your birth date:</h3>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-3" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></input>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-1">GO</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a snippet of your code

Comment: try tracing it back. If the length of arr is null, then either the regex is flopping, or the `$inp` doesn't contain what you think it contains. At a guess, using the `$('input') selector is returning a collection of input elements, which may render unexpected results.

Comment: White-space can greatly increase readability

Comment: Yeah m really sorry for bad formatting guys. I comment out my code for understanding. Well If you go to dev tools and type these specific commands
var $inp=$(“input”).val();
var regex= /(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})/gi;
var arr=regex.exec($inp);
arr
after this you will see arr is array of 4 elements. similarly for loop and arr.length is also working. I confirmed my regex in regex101.com1 too. Its fine. But if I run the same code in compiler it gives arr contains null so cant implement length property

Comment: Have a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The g in your regular expression is only part of the problem. Remove the (regex.test($inp) section of your code and you will see that everything works fine, even with the g.

This is because "if the regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the lastIndex of the regex. A subsequent use of test() will start the search at the substring of str specified by lastIndex (exec() will also advance the lastIndex property)."

This causes regex.exec($inp) to return null, since it is the same regex that was used for test().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

You can simply create a second regex for use with your exec().

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").focus(function() { //whenever user focus at input placeholder value should be mm/dd/yyyy
    $("input").attr("placeholder", "mm/dd/yyyy");
  });
  
  $("button").on("click", function() { //on click function on button GO
    var $inp = $("input").val(); //getting the value of input field
    var regex = /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/gi; //regular expression for date format and use with test()
    var regex2 = /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/gi; //regular expression for date format and use with exec()
  
    if (regex.test($inp) === false) { //if format is not followed input is invalid
      $("input").attr("placeholder", "Please write valid input").val("");
    }
    
    var arr = regex2.exec($inp); //making array of input field value ['12/13/1995','12','13','1995']
    var numarr = [];
    
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { //loop to convert string into numbers
      var n = Number(arr[i]); //converting into numbers
    
      if (i === 1 && n > 12 || i === 2 && n > 31) { //if invalid input day is 32 or month is 13
        $("input").attr("placeholder", "Please write valid input").val("");
      } else {
        numarr.push(n); //if valid push that number into numarr. 
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="head">
  <h1>Whats my alive time</h1>
</div>
<div class="container text-center" id="enter">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <h3 style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 0.5em; ">Enter your birth date:</h3>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-3" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></input>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-1">GO</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, guys I just found out something strange in here. If we remove "g" identifier from regular expression it works.Phewww!!! after 3 hours maybe community proved to be lucky for me but still, I cant understand this behavior. Why is it doing so?